# How to enable 802.1x EAP-TTLS with PAP in Windows 7?

Tags: 802.1, eap, peap

By default, Windows 7 doesn't support EAP-TTLS authentication method natively. If I enable IEEE 802.1X authentication in Windows 7, I can see only two authentication methods:

- Microsoft smart cards or other certificates
- Microsoft: Protected EAP(PEAP)

Some network cards supply their own 802.1X clients, for example Intel, but not all PC use Intel network card. And I believe EAP-TTLS is not a hardware-related solution, it is just a software.

I googled a lot solutions, for example using XSupplicant or WPA_Supplicant, but they all can not be installed successfully(XSupplicant hanged while installing, WPA_Supplicant only gives source code).

So if you know some solution, please share with me, thanks a lot.

[Why I don't choose EAP-PEAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644059/freeradius-eap-peap-with-ldap)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find an easy and open source tool: https://github.com/Amebis/GEANTLink
It adds the ttls option to authentication list. Test working.